# is there a way to use preprocess_page only for certain page templates?

Tags: 7, theming

I have a preprocess_page function in template.php that I need to use to pass a variable into a page (not node) template. The code works where I need it to, but it's also trying to run on EVERY page, which I don't want.

Is there a way to make a `hook_preprocess_page()` function run only on certain page templates, or a different function name (e.g. `mytheme_preprocess_page_speaker()`)?

The preprocess function I am using is the following one.

```
function bluemasters_preprocess_page(&$vars) {

  if ($vars['node']->type == 'session') {
      $sess_type = field_get_items('node', $vars['node'], 'field_session_type');
      $sess_type_name = $sess_type[0]['taxonomy_term']->name;
      $vars['session_type_name'] = $sess_type_name;
  }

}
```

This works on nodes that are of the content type "session", but when I view other pages that use other content types, I get an error message telling me there's an undefined index of 0 on the line that's defining `$sess_type_name`. I need to make it so that the function ONLY runs on nodes of type session.

**updated** it appears the error is only occurring on a view with a page display that displays content type=session. So how can I avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

I made a test using the following code, in my test site.

```
function code_testing_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['node'])) {
    watchdog('code_testing', var_export($variables['node'], TRUE), array(), WATCHDOG_DEBUG);
  }
}
```

I then created a view showing the nodes of a specific content type (in my case, it was snippet). When I visited the view page, and checked the output from `watchdog()`, I have not found any information about `$variables['node']`.
Effectively, that is what I would expect, as `$variables['node']` is set in [template_preprocess_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) using the following code.

```
  if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
    $variables['node'] = $node;
  }
```

Probably, if the view uses a URL like http://example.com/node/1, and there is a node with that node ID, `$variables['node']` could be initialized. Differently, if the view is using a different URL, I would not expect `$variables['node']` to be set.

To notice that [views_preprocess_node()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_preprocess_node/7) uses the following code.

```
  if (!empty($vars['node']->view) && !empty($vars['node']->view->name)) {
    $vars['view'] = $vars['node']->view;
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__view__' . $vars['node']->view->name;
    if (!empty($vars['node']->view->current_display)) {
      $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__view__' . $vars['node']->view->name . '__' . $vars['node']->view->current_display;

      // If a node is being rendered in a view, and the view does not have a path,
      // prevent drupal from accidentally setting the $page variable:
      if ($vars['page'] && $vars['view_mode'] == 'full' && !$vars['view']->display_handler->has_path()) {
        $vars['page'] = FALSE;
      }
    }
  }
```

Probably the first control statement can be used in `hook_preprocess_node()` to check if a view is being served.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to disable the page title display for a certain menu callback via hook_preprocess_page() and came across your thread. The best solution I could find was looking in `$variables['theme_hook_suggestions']`, as follows:

```
// Loads for menu callback 'app'
function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if ('page__app' == $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][0])
    $variables['title'] = false;
}
```